# RxJava timer that repeats forever, and can be restarted and stopped at anytime

Tags: android, rx-java, observer-pattern, rx-android

In android i use Timer to execute task that repeats every 5 seconds and starts after 1 second in this way:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Here is the repeated task
        }
    }, /*Start after*/1000, /*Repeats every*/5000);

    // here i stop the timer
    timer.cancel();
```

this timer will repeat Until i call `timer.cancel()`

I am learning RxJava with RxAndroid extension

So i found this code on internet, i tried it and it doesnt repeat:

```
Observable.timer(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Action1<Long>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Long aLong) {
             // here is the task that should repeat
        }
    });
```

so what is the alternative for the android Timer in RxJava.

Comment: I just started learning RxJava and I'd like to know which one of those (Timer and RxJava) would be better in that approach? I mean related to performance and developing speed

Comment: `Observable.timer` will only fire once and then completes

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**timer** operator emits an item after a specified delay then completes. I think you looking for the **interval** operator.

```
Subscription subscription = Observable.interval(1000, 5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<Long>() {
                public void call(Long aLong) {
                    // here is the task that should repeat
                }
            });
```

if you want to stop it you just call unsubscribe on the subscription:

```
subscription.unsubscribe()
```

Comment: You don't need `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` to start in background  because `Observable.interval` emits on `Schedulers.computation()` by default.

Comment: in RX 2 instead of Action1 you should use Consumer

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the first param is the initial delay. 

        public static Observable<Long> interval(long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit) {
        return interval(initialDelay, period, unit, Schedulers.computation());
    }

Answer (score 11):

Call `Observable.repeat()` method to repeat

```
Disposable disposable = Observable.timer(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
.repeat()
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe();
```

If you want to stop it call `disposable.dispose()`

Comment: Can you tell how to reuse this timer..calling subscribe again will perform the same task twice in TimeUnit intervals.

Comment: @AkshayMahajan use publish() operator for that (possible with replay(1) depending on your case)

Answer (score 3):

> KOTLIN way

```
Observable.timer(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .repeat() //to perform your task every 5 seconds
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe {
                Log.d("ComingHere", "Inside_Timer")
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the right and secure way %100 working :

```
     //timer variable is in seconds unit
    int timer = 5;
    Disposable disposable = Observable.interval(timer, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .map((tick) -> {
                handler.post(() -> {
                    //Enter your CODE here !!!
                });
                return true;
            }).subscribe();
```

And for stoping it :

```
if (disposable != null) {
        disposable.dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I create this method for send time from viewModel to View :

```
fun countTime(start: Boolean) {
        var counter = 0
        var seconds: Int
        var minutes: Int
        if (start) {
            disposable = Observable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .repeat()
                .subscribe {
                    counter++
                    seconds = (counter % 60)
                    minutes = (counter % 3600) / 60
                    val secondFormatter = String.format("%02d", seconds)
                    val minutesFormatter = String.format("%02d", minutes)
                    timeLiveData.postValue(" $minutesFormatter : $secondFormatter")
                }
        } else {
            if (disposable != null) {
                timeLiveData.postValue("00 : 00")
                disposable.dispose()
            }
        }
    }
```