# RxJava Immediate-like Scheduler

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java

`Activity.runOnUiThread()` has this:

```
if (Thread.currentThread() != mUiThread) {
    mHandler.post(action);
} else {
    action.run();
}
```

It means, it runs action immediately if I am in UI thread and posts action to handler if I am not.
I am looking for RxJava Scheduler like this functionality. Does it exists?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RxJava timer that repeats forever, and can be restarted and stopped at anytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38605090/rxjava-timer-that-repeats-forever-and-can-be-restarted-and-stopped-at-anytime)

Comment: The problem with running immediately is that if that `Runnable` also schedules on the main thread, you get a recursion that can lead to StackOverflowError or simply won't give up the main thread for other tasks.

Comment: @akarnokd Sorry but I can't understand you. Can you give an example?

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel Why do you think my question is duplicate of your suggestion? They are different problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's simple.

```
getSomeObservable().observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

after **.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())** you can subscribe to your observable and callbacks will come into main thread.

```
.subscribe(new Subscriber<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.i(TAG,Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.i(TAG,Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Object o) {
                    Log.i(TAG,Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
            });
```

Comment: The `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread` [always posts](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/blob/2.x/rxandroid/src/main/java/io/reactivex/android/schedulers/HandlerScheduler.java#L72), even if the `schedule` call is on the main thread.

Comment: Yes I see. May be Observable.just() will suite, as I know it doing action immediately.

Comment: `just` doesn't run on any particular scheduler. You need an operator that can move subscription/observation to the main thread.