# How to update UI continuosly with RxJava

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to update the UI continuously, but it isn't working,
I want to know how can I achieve the same using RxJava

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
boolean stop = false;

count = 0;
while (true) {
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    count++;
    if (stop) break;
}

// 'stop' variable will be true, after the response from the server.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the answer provided here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38607323/6704680

or alternatively you can simply use CountDownTimer :

```
CountDownTimer counter = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // this happens every 1000ms
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        // this happen after 10seconds or 10000ms
    }

};
counter.start();
```

and you can stop the timer any time by using :

```
counter.cancel();
```